# How to have multiple base URL in retrofit2 using Kotlin and Kodein structure

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit2, kodein

I have followed [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67bdklHmXA8&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hjVaZ8DZKe8iT9RIM9OUrwp) tutorial for MVVM and Retrofit2 with Kodein structure/framework. I wanted to know, Using this same framework/structure how can i have multiple base URLs in a single App.

Below is the code of "MyApi" interface which have an interceptor class as parameter.

```
companion object {
    operator fun invoke(
        networkConnectionInterceptor: NetworkConnectionInterceptor
    ): MyApi {

        val okkHttpclient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(networkConnectionInterceptor)
            .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okkHttpclient)
            .baseUrl("http://my-base-url")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(MyApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

And here is how Iam initializing MyApi interface in Application class:

```
    bind() from singleton { PreferenceProvider(instance()) }
    bind() from singleton { NetworkConnectionInterceptor(instance(), instance()) }
    bind() from singleton { MyApi(instance()) }
```

Here instance() in MyApi is obviously NetworkConnectionInterceptor.

I have seen a lot of examples on stackoverflow and medium but i didnt got any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a work around to achive this. There are two solutions...

**First Solution:**

- You can create a new interface for other microservice (base url) and use it just like the first one. Now there are some pros and cons for this.

**Pros:**

- Both the interfaces will be independent of each other.
- You can use either of the interface or both in same activity as you need.

**Cons:**

- If there is another microservice poped up , you have to create one more interface for that.
- If you even have to 2 microservice and you have to run same application on `development` and `qa` server providing an option for testers and developers to switch between qa and dev servers at run time the you need to have 4 interfaces and 2 extra for `production` that means 6 interfaces, It will become very had to manage it.

**Second Solution:**

- You can use `@URL` annotation provided by retrofit2. Now if you do this there will be no base_url, you have to pass the URL and microservice name in a common function which will return you a full URL based on what server users/testers are on (dev/qa or prod).

**Pros:**

- No extra interfaces, Only one will work out.
- Easy management of all the API calls because of the common function.

**Cons:**

- You have to call the common funtion in `@URL` annotation in each and every API call.
- I dont see any more.